# Python Class handling txtfiles

Tags: python, class, text

I need to write a class, named "data" which handles the processing of a (txt)file into an object.

It needs to take in the classvariable "filename" which will be manipulated with the following 3 functions:

function "init": takes in a string and allocates it to the class variable "filename".

function "reset": produces a new empty file with the name of the class variable. Existing files will be overwritten.

function "save": takes in a string and puts it in the end of the file

This is what I have so far:

```
class File:

    filename = []
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def Reset (self, filename):
        self.filename = open('test.txt').close()

    def Save (self, input):
        self.input = raw_input()
        text_file = open("test.txt", "w")
        text_file.write(self.input)
        text_file.close()
```

I am very new to programming and already tried it to word by myself and hours of googling, but I just can´t get it to work. I would be very thankfull for any help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: Post you code here, unless no one can help you.

Comment: @MikeScotty Sssh, you are not welcoming ;)

Comment: @LutzHorn The link very politely explains why I downvoted - and more importantly, how OP could improve the question. I'd say it's better than just downvoting w/o explanation. Sure, it's not as nice as manually writing "Welcome to SO, please take the tour and read how to ask, please provide a mcve, ..." based on every specific situation, but it saves me time.

Comment: @MikeScotty Your´re right, I can improve the question, I´m sorry. Just don´t jugde me by the code I have so far, I tried now for several hours...

Comment: @Cold2Breath I retracted my downvote. Thanks for improving the question.

Comment: In `Reset` (which should be named `reset`) you should open the file for wrtiting. In `Save` you should open the file in append mode and get rid of `raw_input` and `self.input`. And what do you think `filename = []` does?

Answer (score 0):

> function "init": takes in a string and allocates it to the class variable "filename".

This function you already got right.

> function "reset": produces a new empty file with the name of the class variable. Existing files will be overwritten.

You didn't use the class variable for opening the file, you forgot to use writing mode, and you overwrote the variable `self.filename`. Correct:

```
    def Reset(self):
        open(self.filename, 'w').close()
```

> function "save": takes in a string and puts it in the end of the file

You didn't use the class variable for opening the file, you forgot to use appending mode, and we don't need to store the given string in the variable `self.input`. Correct:

```
    def Save(self, input):
        text_file = open(self.filename, "a")
        text_file.write(input)
        text_file.close()
```